# Shutdown VAIO when it requires a restart?

Tags: windows-8, sony-vaio

Whenever my VAIO laptop auto-updates its VAIO Care/Update/Whatever, it prompts me with: "your VAIO must restart for the installation to complete."
Why would I want to reboot? I don't know. If I just turn off the machine, it will just prompt me with the exact same crap upon the next boot.

How can I just shut down the machine with VAIO Control/Puppetmaster/Hoyvin still completing its installation?
I reckon it's just a tweak in the registry somewhere…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you shutdown the PC in Windows 8, the [new fastStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8) is used. In this case the kernel is hibernated! If a software request a restart, you MUST select restart and not shutdown and turn the PC on again.

Comment: Ah blimey, that makes sense. Isn't there a way to do a regular shutdown just once? :P

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Run `shutdown.exe /s /t 0` to do a full shutdown.